# Google Web App Dynamic Dependent Dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, dropdown, html-select

I've been trying to add 3rd and 4th level dependent dropdown using the code from Code with Curt(https://codewithcurt.com/create-dependent-drop-down-on-google-web-app/), but I'm running into some issues. In this code below, I'm trying to add a 3rd level, but it doesn't seem to work. This is the output I'm trying to achieve. I'm not sure if there's a fastest way to load the dropdown from Google sheets, as this codes loads in about 3 seconds, or a better way to fetch it from Sheets.

[image]

Here's the code:

Google Apps Script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
  var colors = getColors();
  htmlOutput.message = '';
  htmlOutput.colors = colors;
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function doPost(e) {

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));

  var name = e.parameters.name.toString();
  var color = e.parameters.color.toString();
  var fruit = e.parameters.fruit.toString();
  var class = e.parameters.class.toString(); //class is a reserved word

  AddRecord(name, color, fruit, class);

  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
  var colors = getColors();
  htmlOutput.message = 'Record Added';
  htmlOutput.colors = colors;
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();

}

function getColors() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LOV");
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for (var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++) {
    if (return_array.indexOf(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue()) === -1) {
      return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue());
    }
  }


  return return_array;
}

function getFruits(color) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LOV");
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for (var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++) {
    if (lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() === color) {
      return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue());
    }
  }


  return return_array;
}
function getClass(fruit) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LOV");
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for (var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++) {
    if (lovSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() === fruit) {
      return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue());
    }
  }


  return return_array.sort();
}


function AddRecord(name, color, fruit, class) {
  var url = '';   //URL OF GOOGLE SHEET;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  dataSheet.appendRow([name, color, fruit, class, new Date()]);
}

function getUrl() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return url;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function GetFruit(color) 
    {
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {

    console.log(ar);
    
    fruit.length = 0;
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    fruit.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      fruit.appendChild(option);    
    });
    
    }).getFruits(color);
    
    };

 function getClass(queue)
{

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
{

console.log(ar);

class.length = 0;

let option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = "";
option.text = "";
class.appendChild(option);

ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
{    
  let option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = item;
  option.text = item;
  class.appendChild(option);    
});

}).getClass(queue);

};
  </script>


  <h1>Web App Dependent Drop Down</h1>
  <?var url = getUrl();?>
  <form method="post" action="<?= url ?>">
    <label style="font-size: 20px" >Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" style="font-size: 20px" /><br><br>
    <label style="font-size: 20px" >Colors</label><br>
    <select name="color" style="font-size: 20px" onchange="GetFruit(this.value)" >
      <option value="" ></option>
      <? for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) { ?>      
      <option value="<?= colors[i] ?>" ><?= colors[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
      </select><br><br>
    <label style="font-size: 20px" >Fruit</label><br>
    <select name="fruit" id="fruit" style="font-size: 20px" >
      </select><br><br>
    <label style="font-size: 20px" >Class</label><br>
    <select name="location" id="location" style="font-size: 20px" >
  <option value="" selected disabled>Select Class</option>
  </select><br><br>

    <label style="font-size: 20px" >Brand</label><br>
    <select name="location" id="location" style="font-size: 20px" >
  <option value="" selected disabled>Select Brand</option>
  </select><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" style="font-size: 20px" />
    <span style="font-size: 20px" ><?= message ?></span>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In your question, you say `I've been trying to add 3rd and 4th level dependent dropdown`. And, in your current script, it seems that your current issues are `I'm trying to add a 3rd level, but it doesn't seem to work.` and `I'm not sure if there's a fastest way to load the dropdown from Google sheets`. And, when I saw your showing script, on your HTML side, it seems that `getClass` is not called. And, I cannot find the script for the 4th level. And also, I cannot imagine your Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. Can I ask you the detail of your question?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you for your time. I did not include the script for the 4th level yet as I'm still trying to figure out the 3rd level, but I'm looking to have a 4th level dropdown as well. And regarding my sheet I only have two Sheets: "DATA" and "LOV" for the dropdown, it has 4 columns(Color, Fruit, Class, Brand). Example row data: Color: Red, Fruit: Apple, Class: A, Brand: X).

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize. Unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, the image cannot be uploaded. So, now, I couldn't upload a test situation as the image. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. Apologies for late reply. Amazing, this loads much faster. Thank you so much. The only issue I've noticed is the level 4 dropdown which is the brand, it does not dynamically change based on Class selection.

Comment: About `The only issue I've noticed is the level 4 dropdown which is the brand, it does not dynamically change based on Class selection.`, when "Class 1" is changed to "Class 2", the value of "Brand" is changed. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand it, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including my proposed script for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following GAS and HTML:

### Google Apps Script

I have added the [onlyUnique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473) function (from another SO post) to filter out similar entries. I also added other functions to cater the `Class` and `Brand` columns. I also changed the variable `class` to `classParam` since `class` is a reserved word.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
  var colors = getColors();
  var fruits = getFruits();
  var classParams = getClasses();
  var brands = getBrands();
  htmlOutput.message = '';
  htmlOutput.colors = colors;
  htmlOutput.fruits = fruits;
  htmlOutput.classParams = classParams;
  htmlOutput.brands = brands;
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function doPost(e) {
  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  
  var name = e.parameters.name.toString();
  var color = e.parameters.color.toString();
  var fruit = e.parameters.fruit.toString();
  var classParam = e.parameters.classParam.toString();
  var brand = e.parameters.brand.toString();
  
  AddRecord(name, color, fruit, classParam, brand);
  
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
  var colors = getColors();
  var fruits = getFruits();
  var classParams = getClasses();
  var brands = getBrands();
  htmlOutput.message = 'Record Added';
  htmlOutput.colors = colors;
  htmlOutput.fruits = fruits;
  htmlOutput.classParams = classParams;
  htmlOutput.brands = brands;

  return htmlOutput.evaluate(); 
  
}

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

function getColors() { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LOV"); 
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if(return_array.indexOf(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue()) === -1) {
        return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue());
      }
  }


  return return_array.filter(onlyUnique);  
}

function getFruits(color) { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LOV"); 
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() === color) {
        return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue());
      }
  }


  return return_array.filter(onlyUnique);  
}

function getClasses(color, fruit) { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LOV"); 
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if((lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() === color) && (lovSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() === fruit)) {
        return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue());
      }
  }

  return return_array.filter(onlyUnique);  
}

function getBrands(color, fruit, classParam) { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LOV"); 
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if((lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() === color) && (lovSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() === fruit) && (lovSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue() === classParam)) {
        return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue());
      }
  }


  return return_array.filter(onlyUnique);  
}

function AddRecord(name, color, fruit, classParam, brand) {
  var url = "";   //INSERT SPREADSHEET URL HERE <---------
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  dataSheet.appendRow([name, color, fruit, classParam, brand, new Date()]);
}

function getUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
}
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function GetFruit(color) 
    {
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {

    console.log(ar);
    
    fruit.length = 0;
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    fruit.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      fruit.appendChild(option);    
    });
    
    }).getFruits(color);
    
    };

    function GetClass(color, fruit) 
    {
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {

    console.log(ar);
    
    classParam.length = 0;
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    classParam.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      classParam.appendChild(option);    
    });
    
    }).getClasses(color, fruit);
    
    };

    function GetBrand(color, fruit, classParam) 
    {
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {

    console.log(ar);
    
    brand.length = 0;
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "";
    brand.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      brand.appendChild(option);    
    });
    
    }).getBrands(color, fruit, classParam);
    
    };
  </script>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Web App Dependent Drop Down</h1>
    <?var url = getUrl();?>
    <form method="post" action="<?= url ?>" >
      <!-- name -->
      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Name</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name" style="font-size: 20px" /><br><br>

      <!-- color -->
      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Colors</label><br>
      <select name="color" id="color" style="font-size: 20px" onchange="GetFruit(this.value)" >
      <option value="" ></option>
      <? for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) { ?>      
      <option value="<?= colors[i] ?>" ><?= colors[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
      </select><br><br>

      <!-- fruit -->
      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Fruits</label><br>
      <select name="fruit" id="fruit" style="font-size: 20px" onchange="GetClass(color.value, this.value)" >
      <option value="" ></option>
      <? for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) { ?>      
      <option value="<?= fruits[i] ?>" ><?= fruits[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
      </select><br><br>

      <!-- class -->
      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Classes</label><br>
      <select name="classParam" id="classParam" style="font-size: 20px" onchange="GetBrand(color.value, fruit.value, this.value)" >
      <option value="" ></option>
      <? for(var i = 0; i < classParams.length; i++) { ?>      
      <option value="<?= classParams[i] ?>" ><?= classParams[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
      </select><br><br>

      <!-- brand -->
      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Brand</label><br>
      <select name="brand" id="brand" style="font-size: 20px" >
      </select><br><br>

      <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" style="font-size: 20px" /> 
      <span style="font-size: 20px" ><?= message ?></span>
      
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Sample Data

[image]

### Web App

[image]

### Output

[image]

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions with regards to my answer.

Comment: Wooh! Thank you Patrick! Appreciate you man! I just noticed that the brand does not dynamically change based on classes selection.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the bug. Apparently, the filtering for each column is only dependent on the first column to its left. I'll look into it

Comment: Updated both the GAS and HTML. I added additional codes to the conditional statements as well as adding input variables to the other functions. Kindly test it on your side.

Comment: Hey PatrickdC. Apologies for delayed response. You're amazing!! It worked perfectly well. Appreciate your help big time.

Comment: That is good to hear. If my answer helped you, please feel free to accept my answer or give it an upvote so that other users (which may have the same concerns as you) will know that they may use this method that I have provided.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

#### Modification points:

- When a loop process is used using the HTML template, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f1436d88423077115d2c249862f12f17)

  - In this case, the HTML template is used for replacing the values.
- When `google.script.run` is used, the process cost becomes high.

  - In this case, `google.script.run` is used for sending the values to the Google Apps Script side instead of the form submission.
  - From your showing script, I thought that the values might not be required to be sent with the HTML request. So, in this modification, the values are sent with `google.script.run`.
- Creations of the options in the select tag are done in Javascript using the 1st loaded values.
- In your Google Apps Script side, `getValue()` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When these points are reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LOV");
  var [, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
  htmlOutput.values = JSON.stringify(values);
  htmlOutput.message = '';
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function addRecord({ name, color, fruit, clas, brand }) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA");
  sheet.appendRow([name, color, fruit, clas, brand, new Date()]);
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<h1>Web App Dependent Drop Down</h1>
<form>
  <label style="font-size: 20px" >Name</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="name" style="font-size: 20px" /><br><br>
  <label style="font-size: 20px" >Colors</label><br>
  <select id="colors" name="color" style="font-size: 20px" onchange="setOptions('fruit', getValues(this.value, 0))" ></select><br><br>
  <label style="font-size: 20px" >Fruit</label><br>
  <select name="fruit" id="fruit" style="font-size: 20px" onchange="setOptions('clas', getValues(this.value, 1))" ></select><br><br>
  <label style="font-size: 20px" >Class</label><br>
  <select name="clas" id="clas" style="font-size: 20px" onchange="setOptions('brand', getValues(this.value, 2))" ></select><br><br>
  <label style="font-size: 20px" >Brand</label><br>
  <select name="brand" id="brand" style="font-size: 20px" ></select><br><br>
  <input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Submit" style="font-size: 20px" onclick="sample(this.parentNode)" >
  <span style="font-size: 20px" ><?= message ?></span>
</form>
<script>
const values = JSON.parse(<?= values ?>);

function setOptions(id, v) {
  const s = document.getElementById(id);
  s.innerHTML = "";
  v.forEach(a => {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = a;
    option.innerHTML = a;
    s.appendChild(option);
 });
}

function getValues(e, i) {
  return ["", ...new Set(values.reduce((ar, r) => (r[i] == e && ar.push(r[i + 1]), ar), []))];
}

window.onload = function() {
  setOptions("colors", ["", ...new Set(values.map(([a]) => a))]);
}

function sample(e) {
  google.script.run.addRecord(e);
}
</script>
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: ! Apologies for late reply.  Amazing, this loads much faster.  Thank you so much. The only issue I've noticed is the level 4 dropdown which is the brand, it does not dynamically change based on Class selection.

Comment: @coders_key Thank you for replying. About `The only issue I've noticed is the level 4 dropdown which is the brand, it does not dynamically change based on Class selection.`, when I tested my proposed script, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current issue of `it does not dynamically change based on Class selection`, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hi, for example. I have this set of data. When i tried to Filter exampla. Red->Apple->Class 1> the brand dropdowns shosw Brand 1 Brand X and Brand 3. Instead of just Brand 1 and X.
Red Apple Class 1 Brand 1
Red Apple Class 1 Brand X
Yellow Banana Class 1 Brand 3

Comment: @coders_key Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your reply. Can I ask you about the detail of your reply?

Comment: I've updated the screen capture on my original post.

Comment: @coders_key Thank you for replying. When I saw your updated image, I think that "Class 1" is not "Brand 1, Brand 3, Brand X" from your provided sample data. I think that when it's "Class 1", it is "Brand 1, Brand 2, Brand X". So I cannot understand your current issue. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, when "Class 1" is changed to "Class 2", the value of "Brand" is changed. How about this?

Comment: @coders_key Oh! I noticed that your provided data in your reply was changed, just now. I apologize for this. But, when "Class 1" is changed to "Class 2", the value of "Brand" is changed. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand it, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including my proposed script for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.