# want combination of 4 stage, 3 stage, 2 stage dependent drop down in google sheet-web app script

Tags: html, google-sheets-api

ref-https://www.bpwebs.com/crud-operations-on-google-sheets-with-online-forms/
want to use combination of 4 stage, 3 stage, 2 stage dependent drop down in google sheet-web app script
like [Google Web App Dynamic Dependent Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74075131/google-web-app-dynamic-dependent-dropdown)

but Data sheet with result like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKVzY.png)

tried with https://www.bpwebs.com/crud-operations-on-google-sheets-with-online-forms/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: how to provide code? i tried to pest here but its not taking in